# Найти все омоглифы символа

Tags: java, строки, символы

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** необходимо найти все омоглифы заданного символа. Не получилось найти стандартный способ сделать это (просматривал класс Character, но не нашел подходящего метода). Набор символов - все символы Unicode.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли в стандартной библиотеке решение? Если нет, то есть ли решение в какой-либо сторонней библиотеке?

Comment: Может быть вы имеете в виду **омоглифы**? Гомографы имеют отношение к словам, а не к символам.

Comment: @Alice Magic, спасибо за замечание. Меня интересуют омоглифы. Исправил вопрос.

Comment: Интереная задача, творческая. С ходё нашёл решение на Java: https://github.com/codebox/homoglyph , Так же стоит почитать тут, представлен список омоглифов (unicode confusable) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448369/homoglyph-attack-detection-in-email-phishing , так же https://github.com/mpkorstanje/tr39-confusables